# Object not deleted before new is assigned

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, deep-copy

I'm kind of confused, because I was sure this should work different. Take a look at this code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

class derived : public base
{
    private:
    int a = 0;
    int *b = nullptr;
    std::string lol;

    public:
    derived(std::string s) : b(new int(6)), lol{s} { cout << "ctor " << lol << endl; }
    derived(derived const& d) : lol{d.lol + " copy"} {cout << "copy " << lol << endl; }

    virtual ~derived() { cout << "dtor " << lol << endl; delete b; }

    virtual void superFunction() { cout << "OMG " << lol << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    derived a("a");
    derived b("b");
    a = b;
}
```

And the program output with all optimizations off is:

```
ctor a
ctor b
dtor b
dtor b
```

I was sure that in this case compiler should generate code that deletes object `a` and uses copy constructor to create new object. Instead it uses `operator=` that it implicitly declares.

Can someone explain why? Or point me to C++ standard.

Thanks.

Comment: If "the compiler" deletes `a` first, what would it copy into `b`? Anyway, there is no copy here, just assignment.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `a = b;`, compiler calls assignment operator, which will be automatically generated if not present in the code and not marked as deleted. Copy constructor is used only if you try to *initialize* a new object from another object like this:

```
derived a("a");
derived b = a;
```

Also, your code crashes before main returns as it tries to delete `b`, which points to the same memory from `a` and from `b` after `a = b;` default-assignment.

If you want to delete `a` with `derived` destructor after `a = b;` execution, all you need is copy-and-swap idiom. [What is the copy and swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) has a great answer on how to do that in legacy and modern C++. Proper implementation of rule-of-four from that answer will perfectly fit the DRY principle and help you to avoid memory issues. Note the fabulous trick with passing parameter to `operator=` *by value*, which makes compiler select the appropriate constructor (copy or move) and allows you to write only four methods instead of all [five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) of them.